# Member access into incomplete type error: Templatized struct C++

Tags: c++, templates, struct

Pretty new to C++ and having my first try at templates. I created a struct, `treeNode`, having left, right and parent pointers. I want the tree to be able to store multiple data types and hence am using templates. Whenever I try create an instance of the struct in the .cpp file, and then use it to access the left/right pointers of the tree I get this error: Member access into incomplete type struct 'treeNode'. Any idea on what I'm missing?

Here is the code in the .h file(struct definition):

```
template <class T>
struct treeNode {
    node<T> *l;
    node<T> *r;
    node<T> *p;   
};
```

Here is my attempt in the .cpp file:

```
#include "RedBlack.h"

struct treeNode* t;

Tree::Tree() {
    t->l = NULL;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- First of all since you are declaring a recursive `struct`, members should have the same type of the `struct` itself.
- Second thing: templates are not like generics in Java. They don't provide a real available implementation until you replace the type variable with a real type, so you must always use them specialized or by keeping some type variables still unchosen in another template context (eg. the `Tree` class below)

Since you want to have a generic tree, then the `Tree` class should be generic too:

```
template <class T>
struct node {
  node<T> *l;
  node<T> *r;
  node<T> *p;
};

template <class T>
class Tree
{
  private:
    node<T> *root;

  public:
    Tree() : root(nullptr) { }
};

Tree<int> *tree = new Tree<int>();
```

Answer (score 0):

A `treeNode` is nothing -- literally *not a thing* -- without it's template parameters.

You must do:

```
treeNode <int> * t;
```

Or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from that you did not set a template argument it seems you made a typo. Instead of

```
template <class T>
struct treeNode {
    node<T> *l;
    node<T> *r;
    node<T> *p;   
};
```

should be

```
template <class T>
struct treeNode {
    treeNode<T> *l;
    treeNodeT> *r;
    treeNode<T> *p;   
};
```